# Andrioid App Can't Play "opus" files

Tags: android, audio, opus

I'm developing an app to play music files. Recently, I received an "opus" coded file. I'm using MediaPlayer class in order to play files, but with this kind of files I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000 when executing MediaPlayer.create(context, soundURI);
```

The file type is "audio/ogg; codecs=opus"

I tried to play an audio file from whatsapp media dir. If I open this audio on whatsapp, it sounds perfectly, but if I copy and paste it on my app folder's and try to pay with MediaPlayer, nothing happens.

Any idea?? Thanks!!

Comment: As per this doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html Opus only started being supported on 5.0 (aka Lolipop)

Comment: I know, I'm testing on android 5+ moto g

Comment: I have found I need to rename (yes, just rename, not re-encode) my `.opus` files as `.ogg` to get them to be picked up in Android 6.

Comment: @artfulrobot  i cant understand what should i have to do?

Comment: @JavierCancio how to solve this problem? can you please share code

Answer (score 3):

Rename your .opus files to .ogg.